# Android emulator not working with visual studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator

I am pretty new to xamarin , Just tried to implement Hello world on button click . In my .axml file i created button and in .cs file i have written logic to say hello world on button click. when i try to run the application by selecting the android emulator from the provided list of emulators, first application says deploying after that it is going to debug mode though i didn't give any break point, from debug mode it is launching the emulator and program goes out of execution . when i checked the apps in emulator i cant see my application in that . I tried a solution in the forum which says to start the emulator again while it's running but this time i can see my application opening up but with in seconds it says "unfortunately application is closed". Tried to uncheck the fast deploying option but no use. Can any one help me in this .

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnHw);
        myButton.Click += myButton_Clcik;
    }

    void myButton_Clcik(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello world", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }



}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the missing libaot-mscorlib.dll. so, which is usually hidden in a plethora of messages - is easy to fix: disable Android fast deployment. Go to the properties of the Android project, hit tab “Android options”, and unselect “Use Fast Deployment”.

If this doesnot work, do these following steps:

1. Start the Hyper-V manager
2. Select the emulator you are trying to use
3. Right-click, hit settings
4. Click processor
5. Click Compatibility
6. Click checkbox “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version”

Read the article, i guess it will help
https://dzone.com/articles/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-the-debugger-while-de

Comment: Hi, I tried to fix it with first solution it didn't work . So i tried second technique but when i open Hyper-V manager i wasn't able to see any emulators their. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: emulator is not running. if you do not use visual studio emulator than download the visual studio emulator for android and install it. then run a emulator from it.

Comment: when i try to install visual studio emulator for andriod , it is throwing me an error saying "this computer does not support the windows phone emulator which requires the 64". Can you please help me with this.

Comment: update the visual studio and select windows phone 8.1 when modifying

Comment: Thank you . Now, i have Visual Studio Android Emulator . I followed all the steps which you discussed earlier but this time when i execute my application once emulator launches then go to the deploying after deploying  it goes to the debug state. In the debug state it is throwing an error at  Button myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnHw);
        myButton.Click += myButton_Clcik;    Error Message: object reference is not set to instance of an object.